# How to resolve "Could not find SDK "MobileServicesJavaScriptClient, Version=0.2.0.0 "?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have developed an application for the windows store. The application uses data from windows azure. When I recently open that project it pops out the error "Could not find SDK "MobileServicesJavaScriptClient, Version=0.2.0.0". But I do have installed a Windows Azure mobile service for winJS reference.

[image]

But still my project reference itself to the older version. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already added the NuGet reference to the project, you should remove the "MobileServicesJavaScriptClient" reference from your project (under Sociarkfinal --> References) - just select it and click 'delete'. That should solve this issue.

Comment: I got rid of that error carlos. But I couldn't use 

var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(..)
Says windowsAzure is undefined??

Comment: Hey rather downloading the azure client package through the nuget package manager. The following dedicated client setup solved my issue
https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/?LinkID=257545&clcid=0x409

Comment: Amar - that is a very very old version of the SDK and you should be using the one from NuGet. You can go to the portal and download the WinJS quickstart for your service to get a working example of how to configure this correctly.